# Scrapy not entering parse method

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I don't understand why this code is not entering the parse method.
It is pretty similar to the basic spider examples from the doc: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html
And I'm pretty sure this worked earlier in the day... Not sure if I modified something or not..

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class jobSpider(Spider):
    name='jobSpider'
    wd = webdriver.Chrome()
    wd.get("some url")
    wd.switch_to_frame("cible")


def parse(self, response):
    log.start()

    wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(
    (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'blocResultat'))))
    print(wd.page_source)

    stuff=Selector(text=wd.page_source).xpath('//a[contains(@onclick,"win=window.o    pen(\'JobOffs")]').extract() 
    print(stuff)
```

Comment: You're not calling parse at any point. Also, you have self as an argument, is it supposed to be part of a class?

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html see the example. No need to call it. And they put self as argument too

Comment: Either the code you have here is incorrect, or your indentation is wrong. Please fix the indentation to be the same as it is in your script.

Comment: Fixed. It's correct in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `parse(self, response):` method is not part of the `jobSpider` class. If you look at the [Scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-example) you'll see that the `parse` method needs to be a method of your spider class.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class jobSpider(Spider):
    name='jobSpider'
    wd = webdriver.Chrome()
    wd.get("https://www.leforem.be/particuliers/offres-emploi-recherche-par-criteres.html?exParfullText=&exPar_search_=true&exParGeographyEdi=true")
    wd.switch_to_frame("cible")


    def parse(self, response):
        log.start()

        wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(
        (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'blocResultat'))))
        print(wd.page_source)

        stuff=Selector(text=wd.page_source).xpath('//a[contains(@onclick,"win=window.o    pen(\'JobOffs")]').extract() 
        print(stuff)
```

Also, you need to reference the class data in your `parse` method by using the `self.` prefix on any data in the class.

Additionally, you're missing the start_urls list on your spider. Without it, the spider won't know where to start, and will do nothing.

Comment: Can you elaborate? The identation is still wrong sorry, but the parse bloc as one more indent so it is in the class right?

Comment: @dkx22 That is correct. I'll edit my answer to show you exactly what I mean.

Comment: Still not working damnit, as I said I'm sure this used to work. I still have a file with the output this script gave me earlier and I didn't use self.... But still I did as you and the response bellow suggested but nope :/

Comment: @dkx22 "It doesn't work" isn't helpful. Can you update your post with the exact code you're running and the error you're having?

Comment: I made a gist with my code: https://gist.github.com/misterch0c/7ec165f5344a10dd0a69
I have no error message, the problem is that we don't enter the parse method so I don't see the print

Comment: I haven't used Scapy, but from reading the docs, you seem to be missing a `start_urls`/`start_requests`

Comment: MorganThrapp is correct -- without specifying something in `start_urls`, your spider will never start parsing.  Also, using selenium inside a scrapy spider like this seems like probably a dangerous idea.  The [debug docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/stable/topics/debug.html) for scrapy have an explanation of several tools you should consider when your spider is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to access attributes with `self` and `parse` is part of the class.

```
def parse(self, response):
    log.start()
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.wd, 10).until(
    (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'blocResultat'))))
    print(self.wd.page_source)
    stuff=Selector(text=self.wd.page_source).xpath('//a[contains(@onclick,"win=window.o    pen(\'JobOffs")]').extract() 
    print(stuff)
```